# Android ListView becomes visible when adapter is populated

Tags: android, listview, firebaseui

I have a ListView in my Fragment that I want to remain hidden until a button is clicked. I've set its visibility to "gone" in XML and the Fragment's `onResume` for good measure but it's still visible when the screen opens. Toggling the button or pausing and resuming the fragment correctly resets its visibility.

Through some trial and error I found that providing an adapter, or rather having data for the adapter to present, causes the view to ignore its declared visibility and become visible. The adapter extends `FirebaseListAdapter` which loads its data asnchronously.

How can I stop this from happening? I worked around it by wrapping the ListView in a RelativeLayout and modifying its visibility instead, but it would be preferable to simply keep the ListView hidden.

XML:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/projects_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mProjectAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(getActivity(), query);
    mProjectsListView.setAdapter(mProjectAdapter); // remains hidden if this is removed
    mProjectsListView.setEmptyView(noProjects);
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mProjectsListView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // overridden when adapter is used, but works for subsequent calls
}
```

Comment: Ps you can't really stop this from happening as the firebase list adapter basically is trying to reduce your burden of implementing the sync and notify data part.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the firebase list adapter use a normal arrayadapter. Now, put a child event listener on your location. Also put a value event listener on the same location. Use the events fired by the child event listener  to add the data to the arraylist backing your adapter.

The value event listener fires only after all child events are done... Use this to trigger a call to notify the data set changed and you are set.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the adapter initialization code into onCreateView, and set the visibility in onActivityCreated instead:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle)
{
    mProjectAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(getActivity(), query);
    mProjectsListView.setAdapter(mProjectAdapter); // remains hidden if this is removed
    mProjectsListView.setEmptyView(noProjects);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mProjectsListView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // overridden when adapter is used, but works for subsequent calls    
}
```